# Custom button that extends AppCompatButton

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create  custom button that will contain multiple TextViews. I read that I should have it extend `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton` rather than `android.widget.Button`

Here is the code for the custom button class:

```
public class CustomButton extends AppCompatButton {

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

This works as a simple button, but as soon as I add a textview in the activity xml I get the following error, where the error line is the line of the text view

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{me.app/me.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: me.app.CustomButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <me.app.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/increment_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    </me.app.CustomButton>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do I need to write the activity.xml file in a different way if I extend `AppCompatButton` instead of `Button` ?

Comment: You can't add another view inside `AppCompatButton`. As the exception says `cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`, in this case you need to have a view group who can hold more views as children. Imagine of LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Hope this will help to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is basic knowledge, but why is it possible to add another view inside a Button, but not AppCompatButton? It seems unintuitive to me.

Are you're saying to forget making a custom button and just throw a button + a couple of TextViews inside a LinearLayout? I think that would work but in my mind it made sense to have the TextViews as part of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CardView for the same effect...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card0"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:padding="10.0dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="How to Refresh!?"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="How to Refresh!?"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This way you can add as many TextView you want!